# Calcular positivos y negativos en una función de JS

Tags: javascript

Necesito ayuda para calcular mediante un array cuantos números son positivos (primera posición), cuantos son cero (segunda posición) y cuantos son negativos (tercera posición), una vez calculada la cantidad me devuelta la mitad de estos. 
(por ultimo, algún buen libro de JS para arrancar a leer?)

Por ejemplo, `function([1, 2, 0, -1])` debería devolver `[0.5, 0.25, 0.25]`, dado que hay 50% de positivos, 25% de ceros, y 25% de negativos.

```js
function functionNumeros(numero){
var  positivo, negativo, nulo = 0;
var  array_masMenos;

        for (var i=0; i<numero.length; i++){
            if (numero[i] === 0){
            nulo ++}
            if (numero[i] > 0){
            positivo++}
            if (numero[i] < 0){
                negativo++}
    array_masMenos [0] = positivo/numero.length;
    array_masMenos [1]=nulo/numero.length;
    array_masMenos [2]=negativo/numero.length;
           return array_masMenos;
}}
```

Comment: Merli, has agregado una función que pretende resolver el problema, lo correcto para el sitio sería indicar que problemas has tenido y en que podríamos ayudarte.

Comment: No fui claro al subirlo, perdón. El problema que tengo es que me devuelve error al querer ejecutarlo, por eso deje el fragmento de código que tengo armado hasta ahora para ver que hay que cambiar. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

parece que el problema se debe a que tienes el `return` dentro del `for` por lo que tu bucle **sólo hará una iteración**. Prueba a sacarlo del bucle:

```
function functionNumeros(numero){
var  positivo=0, negativo=0, nulo = 0; // Inicializar todas la variables
var array_masMenos=[]; //también el array
    for (var i=0; i<numero.length; i++){
        if (numero[i] == 0)
        {
            nulo ++;
        }
        if (numero[i] > 0)
        {
            positivo++;
        }
        if (numero[i] < 0)
        {
            negativo++;
        }
    }

    /* fuera del bucle */

    array_masMenos [0] = positivo/numero.length;
    array_masMenos [1] = nulo/numero.length;
    array_masMenos [2] = negativo/numero.length;
    return array_masMenos;
}
```

Edito: Esta nueva versión a mi me funciona, puedes probarla [aquí](http://js.do/code/166552). Faltaba inicializar las variables, incluído el array para indicar que es un array.

Comment: Gracias Daniel, pero me sigue pasando lo mismo. ('Cannot set property '0' of undefined')